# openstack neutron command, grep for exact string

Tags: ubuntu, grep

I need to exactly match "router_dallas" in the output below. I am not interested in the string router_dallas1.

```
NetworkNode001:~$ neutron router-list | grep dallas | awk '{print $4}'
router_dallas1
router_dallas
```

I tried using, "neutron router-list | grep dallas | awk '$1 == "dallas" { print $4 }'", but it did not work. Could someone please let me know if there is a better way to filter this output?

Comment: Can you post the complete output of `neutron router-list`?

Comment: NetworkNode001:~$ neutron router-list | grep dallas

| 610503e6-c45e-4d6d-a4f8-e301cb7830d4 | router_dallas1 | {"network_id": "704e5640-a581-4f6f-b212-9e5ed5d37c3a", "enable_snat": true, "external_fixed_ips": [{"subnet_id": "e55c36d5-2ebe-436b-93e0-b6077f360c5e", "ip_address": "10.116.240.164"}]} | False       | False |
| ac5f9918-ed2f-4070-a5dc-ef58d9ba5ab8 | router_dallas  | null                                                                                                                                                                                       | False       | False |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep  '\brouter_dallas\b' input 
`\b` is to put word boundaries.
```

Or

```
grep -w 'router_dallas' input 


from grep help -w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words
```

Comment: This is perfect. It worked, but not sure if it will work if the string contains -

Comment: Not sure, why it is not letting me upvote :( How do I upvote, it's not letting me do that!

Comment: -w does not work in the following:
    inline ` root@myHost:/home/root# openstack volume show vol1 | grep -w 'status'
      | os-vol-mig-status-attr:migstat | None           
      | status        | in-use`

Comment: YOu need to use `-E` to provide multiple inputs as search pattern. 

`openstack volume show vol1 | grep -Ew 'status| os-vol-mig-status-attr:migstat|None|status|in-use'`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$` to match the end of a string and `^` to match the beginning (assuming your stuff is the only thing on the line):

`grep "^router_dallas$"`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the stuff alone and contains lot of other characters as well. But, this is good information!